# Zurb Foundation how to make image fill a cell in a grid row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I want to make an image fill a cell in a grid row. I want to use the CSS `background-size: cover` property to allow it to scale to fill the cell accordingly.

For example:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='medium-6 columns'>
        <div style='
        background: url("/img/picture.jpg");
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;'></div> 
    </div>
    <div class='medium-6 columns'>
        ... bunch of text ...
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get that `div` in the first cell to expand to the entire cell space?

Note, I'm not using an `img` element since I'm trying to get the `cover` behaviour. If there is a way to do that using `img` I can do that instead.

*I don't know if the answer will be Foundation specific or CSS generic. Either will do, provided it works in Foundation grids.*

Answer (score 1):

You can create an equal height container using a few data attributes. Apply the `data-equalizer` attribute to a parent container. Then apply the `data-equalizer-watch` attribute to each element you'd like to have an equal height. The height of `data-equalizer-watch` attribute will be equal to that of the tallest element.

Read more here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your background-image div has no height or width or content.

`.medium-6` will afford width (as a percentage), but not height. If you want the background-image div to be of the same height as the "bunch of text" div, you should use the Zurb Block Grid, which is similar but uses `display: inline-block;` so each sibling inherits the greatest height.

You could also use `display: table-cell` on "bunch a text" and "background image" and `display: table-row` on `.row`.